# Facebook SDK Login - Application Unavailable: The application you're trying to use is either no longer available or access is restricted

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

A user tried to login to my app using Facebook login and they encountered the following error after being redirected to their native Facebook app: "Application Unavailable: The application you're trying to use is either no longer available or access is restricted".

I'm not able to reproduce it and I haven't found much online. The app is available since it's live under Facebook apps and it's being used by existing users. The only option would be that the access is restricted but I'm not sure why. I do know that Facebook launched a security update in March to "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" by default, but this update does not apply to the Facebook SDK according to what I read.

Comment: Do you check the info in Facebook app dashboard?

Comment: Hey, I am getting this error now.. how did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message on Android devices which was caused by setting only development key hashes solved it by adding release key hash, following these instructions: [Setting a Release Key Hash on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash)

Answer (score 3):

This error is also produced if you try to sign up with recently created account. It seems like Facebook has some approval process which takes time. For me new account produced an error one day and worked perfectly on the next one.

To test sign up immediately you should create a test user in Facebook App Dashboard under Roles.